# Parse big xml in Python using cx_Oracle (ORA-06512)

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g, xml-parsing, cx-oracle

I'm a begginer and I trying to write a Python script that will go through Rows and put them into my database

This is a structure of my xml:

```
Root>
    -<SvcNf>
        -<PersonNf>
            -<PersonList>
                -<Row>
                    <SysName>MI6</SysName>
                    <ServerDt>2016-10-28 03:00:12 +03:00</ServerDt>
                    <UID>9457A55E17341AA7ASDEDS057A8BFFF3</UID>
                    <PersID>007</PersID>
                    <Emp_name>James Bond</Emp_name>
                    <EventID>25</EventID>
                    <EventTXT>Drinking alcohol</EventTXT>
                    <CauseEventID>03</CauseEventID>
                    <CauseEventTXT>Martini with vodka</CauseEventTXT>
                    <EventBegda>2017-10-18</EventBegda>
                    <EventEndda>2017-10-18</EventEndda>
                    <AccrualsSum>171.0</AccrualsSum>
                    <AccrualsProz>0.0</AccrualsProz>
                    <AccrualsName>Chinees_</AccrualsName>
                    <OrderNum>P-336</OrderNum>
                    <Perg>0</Persg>
                    <Perk>15</Persk>
                    <Awart/>
                </Row>
                -<Row>
                    .....
                </Row>
                <Row/>
            </PersonList>
        </PersonNf>
    </SvcNf>
</Root>
```

So, when i use this code to Parse XML:

```
# PARSE XML FILE
sql = """   
DECLARE
    xml_value varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
    xml_value := :i_param;
INSERT INTO HR.EVENTS_TST (PersID, Emp_name, EventID, EventTXT...etc.)
    SELECT 
        e.PersID
        ,e.Emp_name
        ,e.EventID
        ,e.EventTXT
        ....
    FROM XMLTABLE('/Root/SvcNf/PersonNf/PersonList/Row' 
    PASSING XMLTYPE(xml_value)
    COLUMNS 
        ServerDt VARCHAR2(512) PATH 'ServerDt',
        PersID VARCHAR2(512) PATH 'PersID ',
        Emp_name VARCHAR2(512) PATH 'Emp_name ',
        EventID VARCHAR2(512) PATH 'EventID',
        EventTXT VARCHAR2(512) PATH 'EventTXT',
        .....) AS e;
commit;
END;"""          
xmlstr = ET.tostring(doc.getroot(), 'unicode')
ora_cursor.execute(sql, {'i_param':xmlstr})
```

So, after that i have Oracle errors ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 5 (`xml_value := :i_param;`)

Comment: Posting the table column types and the Python code would be helpful.

Comment: Also, the length of the xmlstr would be useful as well.

Comment: all columns like in xml with VARCHAR2(512) type

Comment: i had another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47022708/8843645) but i cant understand this mistakes